# relations between flat metric and flat modules

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

The definition of flat metric has two definitions: 1. given a metric norm $F$ on manifold $M$, there exists coordinate charts s.t. for every point $p$, all differentials of the norm is zero, i.e. $\partial^{(n)} F(v) = 0$. 2. For Riemannian metric, Christopher symbols of Levi-Civita connection are all zero. $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} = \Gamma_{ij}^k {\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}}$, here $\Gamma_{ij}^k = 0$.

My question is that:
Is flat metric related to flat modules in homological algebra and flat vector bundles? Can you show it using coordinates symbols?

Comment: There is no relation to flat modules. Every vector bundle is a locally free sheaf and thus flat.

Comment: A vector bundle is flat if it admits a connection with zero curvature. Such bundles arise as bundles associated to representations of $\pi_1$ of the base manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin What is called bundles associated to representations of fundamental groups? Do you mean flat vector bundle is related to simply-connected universal covering space? Can you write it in formulas?

Comment: @LukasHeger Ok, thank you.